# Vertical border between number and code in lstlisting

Tags: listings

what I am trying to achieve is a vertical line between the line numbers and the code in a lstlisting. I have experimented with the frame option a lot, but i guess it is not possible this way, if at all.

As a visual example check out [this css plugin](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/brushes/css.html) which i use on a website. It should look quite simmilar which is why i am asking this question.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option `frame=leftline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{numbers=left,frame=leftline}
\begin{lstlisting}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\makeatletter
%JB Taken from tufte-common.def
\newcommand{\plainauthor}{}%
\newcommand{\thanklesspublisher}{}%
\newcommand{\thanklessauthor}{}%
\renewcommand*{\author}[2][]{%
    \gdef\@author{#2}%
    \begingroup%
    % TODO store contents of \thanks command%
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}%
    \protected@xdef\thanklessauthor{#2}%
\endgroup%
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
{\renewcommand{\plainauthor}{\thanklessauthor}}%
{\renewcommand{\plainauthor}{#1}}%
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\plainauthor}}}{}%
}%
\makeatother

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```